# Applet not displaying images correctly

Tags: java, image, graphics, applet

I am fairly new to java applets and have been trying to make a tortoise and hare race program. The logic worked fine but whenever I add graphics to it is does not display the images. There are no errors when I compile the code but it will not display the images. My code is below and any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Applet
{
    Image tortise;
    Image hare;
    Graphics screen;

    public void init()
    {
        tortise = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "tortise.gif");
        hare = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "hare.gif");
    }

    public void main()
    {
        Random random = new Random();

        int rabbitPos = 0;
        int turtlePos = 0;
        int randomInt;
        boolean raceWon = false;

        while(raceWon == false)
        {
            randomInt = random.nextInt(9);
            if(randomInt < 5)
            {
                turtlePos += 3;
            }
            else if(randomInt < 7)
            {
                turtlePos += 1;
            }
            else if(turtlePos - 6 < 0)
            {
                turtlePos = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                turtlePos -= 6;
            }

            randomInt = random.nextInt(9);

            if(randomInt < 2)
            {
                rabbitPos += 9;
            }
            else if(randomInt < 5)
            {
                rabbitPos += 1;
            }
            else if(randomInt < 6)
            {
                if(rabbitPos - 12 < 0)
                {
                    rabbitPos = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    rabbitPos -= 12;
                }
            }
            else if(randomInt < 8)
            {
                if(rabbitPos - 2 < 0)
                {
                    rabbitPos = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    rabbitPos -= 2;
                }
            }

            screen.drawImage(this.tortise, turtlePos, 30, this);
            screen.drawImage(this.hare, rabbitPos, 150, this);

            if(rabbitPos >= 50 && turtlePos >= 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Tie");
                raceWon = true;
            } else if(rabbitPos >= 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Rabbit Won");
                raceWon = true;
            }
            else if(turtlePos >= 50)
            {
                System.out.println("Turtle Won");
                raceWon = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does getDocumentBase output?

Comment: it returns the url of the html documet. i placed the images in the same directory

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing is calling `main`
2. `screen.drawImage` is not how painting should be done
3. It's very dangerous to use any kind of `loop` in a graphical environment as you may be blocking the thread responsible for updating the screen and/or violating the single thread nature of most UI toolkits
4. Because images are potentially being loaded across a network connection, you should use something like `MediaTracker` to ensure that the images have being fully loaded before trying to paint them

Start by taking a look at...

- [Creating a GUI with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)
- [Performing custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)
- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/)
- [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

I would recommend that until you can make this work using something like a `JPanel` and `JFrame` I would avoid applets as they bring there own set of problems and issues which will just continue to make your life difficult...